# Is there open source audio feature extraction software avaliable?

Tags: audio, thumbnails, pitch, energy

I undertaking a personal project which involves the development of a system which will automatically generate audio thumbnail clips (about 30 seconds in length) from a full length track.

In order to do this I want to look at the energy and pitch of the audio to try and correctly identify its major structural features.

Is there any open source software available that can do energy/pitch extraction? If not I will start looking into alternative methods using MATLAB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the [Echo Nest API](http://the.echonest.com/).  It has a lot of audio analysis capabilities, and I know there's a script bundled in the Remix package that can automagically turn songs into shorter or longer versions (I believe the script is called earworm).

Answer (score 1):

YAAFE (Yet Another Audio Feature Extractor) http://yaafe.sourceforge.net/ does audio feature extraction in MATLAB, Python and C.

Answer (score 0):

Audacity may do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JAudio](http://jmir.sourceforge.net/jAudio.html) which can extract features from an audio.

Answer (score 0):

MARSYAS contains bextract for analysis, can find MFCCs and various other timbral and spectral features. http://marsyas.info/